# How to know when a Warning: setState(...): has been thrown?

Tags: reactjs

I try to fix the following warning

> warning.js:36 Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or
>   mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an
>   unmounted component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the
>   ContainerDimensions component.

but According to trace I can't understand when it happens.

The trace:

```
printWarning    @   warning.js:36
warning @   warning.js:60
getInternalInstanceReadyForUpdate   @   ReactUpdateQueue.js:48
enqueueSetState @   ReactUpdateQueue.js:200
ReactComponent.setState @   ReactComponent.js:63
onResize    @   index.js:83
addListener @   element-resize-detector.js:161
onElementDetectable @   element-resize-detector.js:236
ready   @   scroll.js:561
process @   batch-processor.js:124
processBatch    @   batch-processor.js:37
```

Thanks, Michael.

Comment: can you show the code of ContainerDimensions comp ?? it is happening in that comp.

Comment: @Michael Horojanski would be very useful if you could post code?

Comment: It's a lot of code, maybe exists some way to debug and find the location when the warning has been thrown?

Comment: @Michael Horojanski do you call `setState` method inside `render`?

Comment: check the event binding means all the event method should be bound and make sure if you calling any method from render, there should not be any setState inside that.

Comment: I don't think I use setState inside render according to the documentation it is bad practice, it is a lot of code and I try to find the exact place of the error, some debug stuff that can help me to do that?

Comment: do you use react-resize-detector ?

Comment: No, I don't use react-resize-detector.